# Talend Studio Environment Setting

Tags: talend

I installed sqoop, hadoop, spark and some python modules on my Mac.
The bash_profile files have added the path so that sqoop and hadoop can be used in terminals.
However, those commands cannot be found when using tSystem in Talend Studio.

Does anyone know how to import the environment paths to Talend Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to load your bash_profile in the component  before executing your specific commands ?

```
cd && source .bash_profile && yourCommands...
```

Regarding the user who launch the job has the right bah_profile in his home directory.

Not tested

Comment: it throws exception cannot find program source

Comment: I add this as a single command in the component : `new String[]{"/bin/bash","-c","cd && source .bash_profile &&  yourCommands"}` and it works

Comment: I do a second test, the source command is not necessary for me, all my specifisc commands are availables

Answer (score 0):

**First**, check that in your .bash_profile the PATH is properly exported using the export command, like this:

```
export SPARK_BIN=/spark/bin
export PATH=$SPARK_BIN:$PATH
```

If you have forgotten to export your variables, it should be the reason of the issue you are facing

**Second**, depending of your system, the .bash_profile may not be called when running a shell script. 
Bash may look in one of these files too, and only these depending on how your job is runned by tSystem:

```
$HOME/.profile
$HOME/.bashrc
```

Ensure that the PATH is also set in these files too.

**Third**, you may run your command in tSystem using the full path to SPARK_BIN if it is easier for you, but will be less portable.

Or, you can run a bash script in tSystem that is starting with

```
#!/bin/bash
export SPARK_BIN=/spark/bin
$SPARK_BIN/spark <your params here>
```

It should help to work around.

**Fourth**, if it can help, in a tJava, copy/paste this code:

```
    Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
    for (String envName : env.keySet()) {
        System.out.format("%s=%s%n",
                          envName,
                          env.get(envName));
    }
```

It will display environment variables as seen by your job.
Do not forget to set the import in advanced setting of the tJava:

```
import java.util.Map;
```

**Finally**, the tSystem component allow to provide additional command line parameters to your job, you could try to set $PATH here:
[image]

Or, better than what is displayed on screenshot, pass PATH variable like this in value column:

```
System.getenv().get("PATH")
```

Hope it can help.